# c# eventhandling error

Tags: c#, datagridview, event-handling

i have method

```
private void getValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(dgvTable.Rows[dgvTable.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        var values = from c in v.db.TotalDoc
                     where c.TotalID == id
                     select c.TotalAmount;
        dgvValues.DataSource = values;
    }
```

and datagridview "dgvTable"
error at this line

```
dgvTable.CellClick += new EventHadler(getValues);
```

error text is: No overload for 'getValues' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

please help!

Answer (score 2):

The `DataGridView.CellClick` method signature is a `DataGridViewCellEventHandler` and not of type `EventHandler`.  Change your method signature to this:

`private void getValues(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`

and also change your declaration to this:

```
dgvTable.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(getValues);
```

Comment: private void getValues(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) - the same error. doesn't work.

Comment: @bragin.www: you need to also change your declaration as well

Comment: one more question. error disappeared but event have no effect after calling the CellClick() method of the dgv. may be i should add some more code?

Comment: @bragin.www: I would actually just post another question.  It's better than re-editing and re-answering.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033609/c-sharp-datagridview-cellclick-method-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2):

```
private void getValues(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
```