# DataGridView.CellClick method doesn't work

Tags: c#, datagridview, event-handling

```
//FormLoad    
dgvTable.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(getValues);

//somwhere in FormClass
private void getValues(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(dgvTable.Rows[dgvTable.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        var values = from c in v.db.TotalDoc
                     where c.TotalID == id
                     select c.TotalAmount;
        dgvValues.DataSource = values;
    }
```

i have two datagridviews (dgv) on the form. I choose dataID from first dgv (dgvTable) and get all values of these id in the other dgv.
but e method dgvTable.CellClick() have no effect. i'm getting emtpy dgv.
please help

Comment: Did you set a break point at `getValues` to check if it's raised ? Or might be you're getting a wrong value that don't match with `v.db.TotalDoc`

Comment: i use MessageBox.Show(id.ToString()). it works. all tables have values

Answer (score 1):

Ok after your comment i just recommend that you use `.ToList()` to help grid to recognise the data source :

```
 int id = int.Parse(dgvTable.Rows[dgvTable.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
 var values = (from c in v.db.TotalDoc
               where c.TotalID == id
               select c.TotalAmount).ToList();
 dgvValues.DataSource = values;
```

Comment: when i add to my method `MessageBox.Show(values.First().ToString());` its shows first value in the message window. when i add `.ToList()` (as you've suggested) it shows only one item in dgv and column HasValue is added too. May be you know some other way to make the query work correct.

Comment: Column<CheckBox> is added. I remove it with `dgv.Columns.RemoveAt(0)`. thank you for ToList(). it works. my mistake that i use `v.db.TotalDoc`. i should use table `v.db.DocTable`. sorry). thank you for help